# Strange problem in connecting MSSQL Server from ASP.NET API project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config, connection-string

Don't know how to put this strange issue that I am facing. I have an ASP.NET API project which connects to a MSSQL Server database. Both reside at my local.

This is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="xxxxx" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname;uid=sa;Password=*****;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The problem is some endpoints are showing connection error while some are connecting fine and displaying records correctly. The error that I am receiving is:

> {   "Message": "An error occurred while calling the
> XmanApi.Controllers.UnitModelController+d__1 method
> in d__1",   "InnerException": "Login failed for user
> 'sa'." }

I checked the entire solution and made sure that all the endpoints are referring to the same connection string.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It should have more details as to the cause of the login failed error.

Comment: "some endpoints" I don't understand: are they connecting remotely, or are only applications on the same machine connecting?

Comment: Do any of the endpoints make use of a [ConnectionStringBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders) to rewrite portions of the connection string?

Comment: @Charlieface both the API system and the database reside on the same PC on localhost.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I will check. Actually this problem has started only yesterday. Before that everything was working fine and nothing was modified in code or database!

Comment: @Charlieface, by "some endpoints", I meant to say some API URL is working and some are not. For example `localhost/api/getById/{id}` while `localhost/api/searchModel/{string}` doesn't. Before yesterday both of them were working perfectly fine and nothing in API code or in Database was changed.